# How to change title of the razorpay widget?

Tags: javascript, html, razorpay

I have implemented razorpay-widget which looks like :

[image]

I want to change the title "Offers and Pay Later" to "Offers and Pay Later (EMI accepted)".
I have read the official [docs](https://razorpay.com/docs/payments/payment-gateway/affordability/widget/native-web-v2/customise/#3-themes-and-colours). There I found to change font-size & color of the title. They don't mention how can we change the title.